# Error Key Already Exists in Table when scaffolding controller vs2015

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I am trying to follow the Music Store Example in Professional MVC 4 using VS2015. I am having issues scaffolding the music store controller. Everytime I try to create the controller a Error window pops up and the only information in it is: "There was an error running the selected code generator:'Key already exists in table.'"

I have searched around for this specific errors but most of the scaffolding error solutions seem to be about errors in the web.config, yet nothing has even changed in my web.config, it is the default one created when the new project was created.

I have tried creating another MVC project and coding the models again yet I still receive the error.

I am using Microsoft Visual Studio Enterprise 2015 version 14.0.247200 Update 1 if that helps.

The Classes that I have created in the Models folder are as follows and are exactly as they are in the book:

```
public class Album
{
    public virtual int AlbumId { get; set; }
    public virtual int GenreId { get; set; }
    public virtual int ArtistId { get; set; }
    public virtual string Title { get; set; }
    public virtual decimal Price { get; set; }
    public virtual string AlbumArtUrl { get; set; }
    public virtual Genre Genre { get; set; }
    public virtual Artist Artist { get; set; }
}

public class Artist
{
    public virtual int ArtistId { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual string Description { get; set; }
}

public class Genre
{
    public virtual int GenreId { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual string Description { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Album> Albums { get; set; }
}
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: Are you using a new folder when you have tried creating a new project? I have seen similar errors when the files VS is trying to generate already exist on the file system.

Comment: It seems to me that ASP.NET and MVC are currently undergoing radical change and all existing books on MVC4 and even MVC5 seem to use VS 2013 or earlier that I probably should wait for books on MVC6 in order to learn this stuff and avoid frustration. Why are MVC 5 projects created in VS 2015 Community having problems with such things as scaffolding code from MVC 5 code from current books like Pro ASP.NET MVC 5? What's changed?

Comment: Seconded. They should have a core of tutorials and make sure they revise them and keep them working as they evolve the platform. Otherwise you get 25% through following something and get to a point where you're cast adrift.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I had the same problem.  I'm using Visual Studio Communitty 2015.
Try a Model Class with the code:

```
public class MusicStoreDB : DbContext
{
    public MusicStoreDB() : base("name=MusicStoreDB")
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Album> Albums { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Artist> Artists { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Genre> Genres { get; set; }
}
```

At the add controller window, use MusicStoreDB as the context.

Working code can be found [here](http://www.wrox.com/WileyCDA/WroxTitle/Professional-ASP-NET-MVC-5.productCd-1118794753,descCd-DOWNLOAD.html).

The code for Chapter 4 looks like it has been generated from database so MusicStoreDB class is slightly different.

Comment: Manually adding this class to the Model folder as Jan suggests seemed to work for me. However, the point is that the scaffolding wizard is meant to actually create this file rather than you having to manually create it first. There's no errata information about this on the Wrox website either. Very confusing and no clear answer for this problem yet. Hopefully I'm not going to have problems later on in the chapter due to this manual addition of the class. If all goes well I'll mark this as a working answer.

Comment: After some head scratching it does appear that you only run into problems if you choose to let the scaffolding wizard also create the **MusicStoreDB** class. Creating it first as Jan suggests here and selecting the class in the drop down menu rather than clicking the + button to get the scaffolding tool to create it for you is definitely the way to go. I've also learned that you should always do a quick build before using any scaffolding templates as a good habit to get into. I'm assuming this places any new class names into Visual Studios symbols table so the scaffolding tool can find them.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issues 'Key already exists in table.' in VS 2015 Pro and found that if I closed all the open windows of code, ran a clean and then a rebuild and tried the scaffolding option again, everything worked perfectly!

Answer (score 2):

Same issue for me on VS 2015 Community Edition.

I was able to get scaffolding to work only if I commented out the following in Album class:

```
public virtual Genre  Genre { get; set; }
public virtual Artist Artist { get; set; }
```

After scaffolding you can uncomment and fix up the controller and view.

Comment: I had to also remove the ForeignKey attribute for the appropriate property.

Answer (score 1):

Earlier my colleagues was working with EF and it was highlighted that to make it work properly the packages and the version of the packages is very important.If not getting exactly right,various unrelated error messages may appear like the "Key already exists in table error" message when trying to use EF.

Since they are using it, i decided to read the wrox book Professional ASP.NET MVC 5 and was going through chapter 4 when i encountered the same error as you all.Anyway i downloaded their sample solution chapter 4 from

http://www.wrox.com/WileyCDA/WroxTitle/Professional-ASP-NET-MVC-5.productCd-1118794753,descCd-DOWNLOAD.html

as suggested and i copy the package folder from their sample and replace the package folder in my project and it works.The StoreManageController is created

Now please do feedback if this works for all.It worked for me.I am using VS2015 Professional

Comment: Dear all please test it out before voting down :),because i don't see any working solution online for that chapter 4 wrox example and it worked for me.If doesn't really work then its okay.I am using VS2015 Professional.Anyway if it works for you,do vote it up and get the word out.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure every single Property is marked as `virtual` in the samples? I don't see how it makes any sense for `Name`, `Price`, etc to be navigation properties.

Try the following, setting only navigation properties (things with relationships) to virtual.

```
public class Album
{
    public int AlbumId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public string AlbumArtUrl { get; set; }
    public int GenreId { get; set; }
    public virtual Genre Genre { get; set; }
    public int ArtistId { get; set; }
    public virtual Artist Artist { get; set; }
}

public class Artist
{
    public int ArtistId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}

public class Genre
{
    public int GenreId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Album> Albums { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Yes they are all marked virtual in the book, I also thought it was a bit unusual. I changed them to the code you provided but it still will not work, not sure if there is something configured incorrectly with my VS or what. Thanks

Comment: The book explains that marking things virtual helps Entity Framework 'hook onto' the class properties in order to improve database versioning when performing migrations.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and resolved it by selecting for "Data context class:" the context from {ConnectionName}Entities ({MyProject}.Models) vice ApplicationDbContext ({MyProject}.Models).

Answer (score 0):

Remove the foreign key properties:

```
public virtual int GenreId { get; set; }
public virtual int ArtistId { get; set; }
```

Comment: I had to also remove the ForeignKey attribute for the appropriate property.

Answer (score 0):

In my case this was caused by selecting incorrect Data context class in the dialog "Add Controller". My project contented 2 data context classes and I was creating a new controller for a model class which already used in another data context class. Change of data context class solved this error( Key already exists... ) in my case. Cleaning, rebuilding, restarting VS(VS 2015 Pro ) didn't help.

Answer (score -1):

I too faced this issue with my model. I just added [ForeignKey("")] attribute to the key to make it work.

Comment: This compiled but broke the tutorial later on for me when I tried to view the examples on the help pages for the api. Wrapping the navigation properties in `DbSet<Album>` did not have any negative side effects.