# Key Already Exists in Table when Scaffolding

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, visual-studio-2015

I am doing a `code first` example, and basically I have `Products` and `Categories`.

The Category Model is as follows :

```
public class Category
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

and the `Product` model is as follows:

```
public class Product
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public decimal Price { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int Stock { get; set; }

    public string ImageName { get; set; }

    //Category Navigation
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public Category Category { get; set; }
}
```

When I try to create a `Controller` with the `Web API 2 Controller with actions`, using `Entity Framework scaffold`, I am getting an error :

> There was an error running the selected code generator : 'Key already
>   exists in table'

I am suspecting its the `Category` Navigation part of the `Product` Model since without that code, the scaffold works.

What am I doing wrong? I tried to create it as a virtual property but I am still getting the same error.

Comment: Have you tried declaring the `CategoryId` as a foreign key with the `[ForeignKey]` attribute?

Comment: @Zippy yes i tried with the ForeignKey attrib but still getting the same error

Comment: You could try changing the name of attribute `id` in Category to `CategoryId`. and also mention the many realtionshiop of Property in the Category model

Comment: @Vini I also tried that but no success

Comment: @Vini yes that too I tried, but still no success. That is why I ran out of ideas what could have happened

Comment: have you added the model in your `DbContext ` ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103469/discussion-between-johann-and-vini).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34422054/5243291 this link should help.

Comment: @Vini ok I will have a look.  Funny thing is that Product alone, the scaffolding works, then when I add the category, it fails!

Comment: You will have to add the models in your DbContext and it shoudl work.

Comment: @Vini ok it seems like its working now as you said, have to add them 1 by 1 and seems to be working!  Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Vini can you add an answer so that I can accept as the answer, or is there any other way to accept your answer?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to add the Model classes in your DbContext

```
    public DbSet<Product> Products{ get; set; }
    public DbSet<Category> Categories{ get; set; }
```

Now you could do the scaffolding.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34333966/error-key-already-exists-in-table-when-scaffolding-controller-vs2015) question will also help for a better understanding