Visual Studio 2022 Error: An item with the same key has already been added
I have a strange issue with my Visual Studio 2022 instance and I believe its a bug with VS2022, but wanted to share here first to see if anyone can help me resolve or workaround it.
Whenever I try to scaffold a new item in my MVC project I receive the error "An item with the same key has already been added" (Image below)

This happens when I try to create a new area, controller, view, basically anything that MVC would normally scaffold for you. The error appears as soon as you click 'Add Area' or 'Add Controller', so I don't think its model related, given I've not even chose whether to scaffold using a model or just basic CRUD.
I have tried the following to resolve so far:

Restarted VS2022
Checked for updates and installed them (Current version 17.2.23)
Deleted my project obj and bin folders and rebuilt the solution

Does anyone have any thoughts on what could be causing it?
Thanks
Steve

The latest version according to VS 2022 release notes is 17.10.5.

Maybe see if the answers on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34333966/error-key-already-exists-in-table-when-scaffolding-controller-vs2015 help

@phuzi you're right, I checked for updates and the version I have isn't showing any. I'll uninstall and install the latest version. Fingers crossed!

It seems unusual that VS Installer doesn't find the updated version.

It was an LTSC version, I presume its been installed by my employer. When I downloaded the new installer, it then told me that my current version was unsupported. So I had to do the long a tedious task of uninstalling and re-installing (because VS2022 is a very light install lol)

Just to close this out, the uninstall and re-install has worked... god knows what had happened, but the scaffolding is working now, so I assume it was a fixed bug.
